# Comparing NSString to UITextField text never gets called

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, uitextfield

I record the value of the text in my `UITextField` and I want to compare the text to the original text field value later. I try something like this, but I never get the `NSLog` to be displayed. Any ideas why?

```
defaultTopicText = topicTextField.text;
if ([topicTextField.text isEqualToString:defaultTopicText]){
    NSLog(@"YES");
}else{
    NSLog(topicTextField.text);
    NSLog(defaultTopicText);
}
```

The code looks *exactly* like you see it. The first line I assign the value and the other - I compare with it. And it's not being called.

**EDIT:**

The code itself **IS** getting called and I also get the same values when I put them in `NSLog`. Might the problem be that the text field contains `@"\n"` characters?

`NSLog` gives me this:

```
2013-03-18 20:45:22.037 myapp[524:907] 

Here comes the text
2013-03-18 20:45:22.039 myapp[524:907] 

Here comes the text
```

Comment: When is this code being called? Did you set a breakpoint to check if it's really being called?

Comment: @CainaSouza in the `ViewDidLoad`

Comment: There are some @"\n\n" in there

Comment: Have you verified that `topicTextField` is not `nil` at the time this is called?

Comment: @SergiusGee OK, set a breakpoint on the `if` statement. When you reach the breakpoint, print the value of `defaultTopicText` and `topicTextField.text`. What do you get?

Comment: @rmaddy when putting NSLog there I get absolutely the same values

Comment: write `else` and again nslog both the values...

Comment: @SergiusGee Putting what log where? There are only two possible reason your `NSLog(@"YES");` doesn't appear. 1) The code is never reached at all, or 2) `topicTextField` is `nil`.

Comment: @rmaddy check out my edit. In the else statement I put the `NSLog` and it prints out two same values

Comment: @SergiusGee Update your question with the updated code (the `else` part).

Comment: @rmaddy Check it out, I have

Comment: And just to be 100% sure, the code you show in this post was copy and pasted from your actual, running iOS app code? There is no tweaking of any kind by you when posting this question?

Comment: You you use `NSLog(defaultTopicText);` intead of `NSLog(@"%@",defaultTopicText);` although no error.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I know I do, it changes nothing

Comment: if this was from osx, i could have said binded to some other object and getting changed at the same time while comparing.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Why would that be a problem? There is no format.

Comment: Can you please mail us your project....

Comment: @AnoopVaidya maybe you also want my Social Security number and the password from my credit card? Anything else?

Comment: plz plz :p .  Since I join SO, this one is easiest and interesting question. So I asked. If you felt bad. No need to send and Sorry.

Comment: @SergiusGee I just can't see why the `if` statement isn't working. Just for fun, try changing the `if` statement to `if ([topicTextField.text isEqualToString:topicTextField.text])`. What happens?

Comment: @rmaddy It's NOT getting called. I don't have an idea about wtf is happening

Comment: @SergiusGee Here's a question - if this is a text field (not a text view), how does the text value have two leading new lines? Now try `if (defaultTopicText isEqualToString:topicTextField.text])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to print out the value of the `topicTextField.text` and see what is shows. otherwise set the breakpoints to see if you are reaching to that particular line of code.

You coud also try comparing after removing the white spaces and new line, if there might be any

```
NSString *trimmmedText = [topicTextField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

if ([trimmmedText isEqualToString:defaultTopicText]){
    NSLog(@"YES");
}
```

Comment: How can this be the issue? He assigns the text field's text to a variable then compares the variable to the text field's text. This should compare equal no matter what text is in place.

Comment: @rmaddy `if ([topicTextField.text isEqualToString:defaultTopicText]){`he is checking the textfield text with the assigned text, so he might have white spaces or newline withint textfield.

Comment: @nsgulliver But the assigned text is the text field text. They can't be different. It doesn't matter how much whitespace there is.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes you are right, if he is assigning the same text then it wont be an issue, but the best way is to just print out the value of textfield and setting breakpoint to see what comes there

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to this:

```
NSString *newString = [defaultTopicText stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

if ([newString isEqualToString:defaultTopicText]){
    NSLog(@"YES");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I typed the following the figured out the answer...
running this should give you your answer:

```
if(!defaultTopicText){
    NSLog(@"defaultTopicText is nil");
}else{
    NSLog(@"defaultTopicText is a: %@".[defaultTopicText classname]);
}

defaultTopicText = topicTextField.text;
if ([topicTextField.text localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:defaultTopicText] == NSOrderedSame){
    NSLog(@"YES");
}else{
NSLog(@"\"%@\" != \"%@\"",defaultTopicText, topicTextField.text);
}
```

Then I realized: `topicTextField.text` can only not be the same object as itself using this comparison method if it is nil.

`topicTextField.text` has to be `nil`... so it ends up executing:

```
id var = nil;
[var isEqual:nil];
```

and the runtime makes that return 0;

... so fix your outlet to `topicTextField`